# Keep fresh data in memory for Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io, relational-database

I am creating a Node.js web application utilizing Socket.IO.
Currently I use Passport.js and its middleware for Socket.IO, which provides me `user` object (which is loaded from MySQL by Passport.js deserialising logic) of authenticated user for each socket:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  const user = socket.request.user;
  socket.on('event', (data) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

However, data in `user` is fixed (being loaded in the moment of connection), so I cannot use any «non-static» properties of user in callbacks for socket events.
Example: user sends chat message and I want to broadcast it to this user's current room (identified by `user_id` field of user in MySQL). Querying relatively slow MySQL each time event comes is obviously not an option (I am also going to have some events being sent a lot of times per second, like real-time drawing).

**Question #1:** What is correct way to solve such task? I currently have Redis in mind (i.e. keep required or all data duplicated in Redis and check Redis on each event (should be fast enough?)).

**Question #2:** If using Redis as I described is an acceptable method, then what is the best practice for maintaning such duplicated data? I mean any code that changes some «need-to-be-fresh-in-redis» data in database now has to update it in Redis too. Maybe create some extra level of abstraction in code, roughly like `userService.setRoom()` updating both DB and Redis, and this method must be called everywhere instead of direct changes like before? Sounds like a decent amount of extra work, but I am not sure about another ways to achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We would likely need to see the rest of your code that creates and maintains `user`.  If `user` is a live object and modifications to the user change that live object, then what you have above should work just fine.  If modifications are not made to that specific user object, but rather to a database somewhere, then you should not be surprised that your `user` object does not get updated.  Unless you are using clustering, you shouldn't need redis to solve this.  The issue is how you store and update your user properties.

Comment: @jfriend00, no, `user` is not a live object, otherwise this problem would not exist. As I said, `user` is data fetched from MySQL. I am not surprised that it does not get updated, rather I am asking for a solution.

Comment: The solution is to make it a live object.  Centrailize your code that modifies the user object so it all goes through a few central methods and then just keep this live object up-to-date.  Yes, you could switch to redis and query it from there everytime, but there is really no need as all you're doing in that case is trying to use redis as a faster DB than the one you already have.  What you need is a live, cached value of the `user` object so you can just reference it when needed.

Comment: @jfriend00, but how is that better than Redis? I need my data to be persisted, I have to update MySQL anyway, so these `few central methods` still must update both DB and in-memory object. Exactly as my Redis option, but Redis enables horizontal scaling, whereas in-memory object ruins it.

Comment: If you need access of live object from multiple processes go with redis for sure - you did not list that as a requirement.  But, redis is generally ram-based, so unless you're using it with something else, I'm not sure how you're getting persistence from redis.  Are you seriously talking about using both redis and your sql database and maintaining a copy of the same object in both?    If you use sticky load balancing, and you are only modifying relevant properties on the user object from the logged in user session, then you don't need horizontal access from multiple processes.

Comment: But, if you've already convinced yourself that you're going with redis, then it sounds like you already know your answer.  Keep in mind that redis is still accessing data in a database in another process.  It's typically data in RAM so perhaps faster than data in a disk-based database, but certainly not as fast as something cached in RAM in the local process.  And, with your proposed solution you will have to write everything to two databases at once and have really good error handling in case of errors in either to avoid losing perfect synchronization of the two.

Comment: Also might want to see if proper caching in your sql database works just as well as adding redis (or good enough).  In your socket.io requests, you will be reading objects that have recently been accessed so they could/should be cached already.  In other words, I'd recommend testing your best sql configuration to verify it doesn't actually meet your needs before adding extra level of complication with redis shadow copy.

Comment: @jfriend00, `Are you seriously talking about using both redis and your sql database and maintaining a copy of the same object in both?` - yes, I am. Either full copy or only relevant for sockets pieces of it. Is it wrong way? 
` I'm not sure how you're getting persistence from redis.` - Redis supports persistence by default, so I could also go the «solo Redis» way and store everything in it, though its different paradigm (to store a lot of relational data in Redis) which I am not sure I want to study right now.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for your answers, anyway. I gonna give a try to the simplest solution as you proposed - pure MySQL and then benchmark it, though I guess there will be necessity to later introduce Redis anyway, if load becomes bigger.